# Detecting dimension of an object with opencv + python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I am working on a small image processing project with raspberry pi.I am using opencv and python.I want to detect dimension of an object ON the image like square,rectangle etc. by pixel value(Width and height).I used canny edge detection an i have binary form of an image(0,255) binary format.So what can i do for getting width and height values of object?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some example images?

Comment: Sorry,I cant give an image,the site gives me an error "reputation is under 10"..You can think a white/black cola can.Background is black and edges of can is white.